# How to generate a Street View URL/hyperlink using SQL? (UTM to WGS84)

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, st-geometry, url, google-street-view

I have a point feature class in an Oracle 18c GDB that is projected as NAD83 UTM 17N (SRID = 26917).

I would like to extract the X&Y coordinates from the points as WGS84 **latitude & longitude** decimal degrees (using SQL).

- The coordinates would be used to generate a Google Street View **URL** (hence the [lat/long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387942/google-street-view-url/542965#542965)).

---

I think this can be done by using SDE.ST_GEOMETRY's [ST_TRANSFORM](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-transform.htm) function:

> ST_Transform takes two-dimensional ST_Geometry data as input and
>   returns values converted into the spatial reference specified by the
>   spatial reference ID (SRID) you provide.

However, I'm stuck on the SRID part:

```
sde.st_x(sde.st_transform (shape, ??????)) as longitudex
```

Is there a specific SRID I should be using to convert the UTM points to WGS84 lat/long?

Comment: This depends on *which* geographic coordinate system you want to target. NAD83? WGS84?

Comment: @Vince Ah, right. NAD83. I've updated the question.

Comment: Doesn't Google use WGS84? And what is the exact SRID of your UTM (there are thousands, not including the infinite number of custom UTMs possible), because you may need a transformation as well.

Comment: 4269 for NAD83, 4326 for WGS84. http://www.epsg-registry.org

Comment: @Vince The SRID of the original UTM 17N feature class is 26917. I've updated the question.

Comment: For my records, this is how to convert UTM 17N to lat/long via a geometry service: `https://<my host name>/server/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer/project?inSR=26917&outSR=4326&geometries=682505.018593456%2C+4958027.56692643&transformation=&transformForward=true&vertical=false&f=json`

Answer (score 0):

As @Vince suggested, [Google Maps uses WGS84](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/52211/135445).

And as @mkennedy pointed out, the SRID of WGS84 is 4326 ([epsg-registry.org](http://www.epsg-registry.org/)).

Therefore, the SQL to generate the [hyperlink](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/using-hyperlinks.htm)/URL would be:

```
select
    'http://maps.google.com/maps?q=' || chr(38) || 'layer=c' || chr(38) || 'cbll=' 
    || latitudey_dd || ',' || longitudex_dd as street_view_url
from
    (
    select 
        sde.st_x(sde.st_transform (shape, 4326)) as longitudex_dd,
        sde.st_y(sde.st_transform (shape, 4326)) as latitudey_dd 
    from assets
    )
```

Output: http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=44.6790448,-75.8618236

Street View URL info here: [Google street view URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387942/google-street-view-url/542965#542965)

---

> Hint:
>
> In Toad, the ampersand was being interpreted as a variable.  I had to escape/replace the ampersand with `||chr(38)||`. [Escaping
>   ampersand character in SQL string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12961550/10936066)

Comment: Unfortunately, there's going to be some datum transformation shift, because Oracle doesn't support the three parameter form of `ST_Transform` and NAD83 isn't quite WGS84. Melita can probably give you the error off the top of her head, but you might want to try adding a column or creating a join table with the meat of the URL string, so you can populate it more accurately using GIS tools (and you wouldn't pay the reprojection cost with each access, either).